# Create TreeAnnotation Parser on sentence (String) in Stanford CoreNLP Java

Tags: java, casting, nlp, stanford-nlp

I want to use **TreeAnnotation.class** of **Stanford CoreNLP**. I have the code how to do it.

```
My issue is different.
```

I have my **own sentences** that are **String**. I converted those **sentences into List Class**. At the time of casting, I set almost all annotations like, **Token, BeginPosition, EndPosition** etc but I **don't** know how to set **TreeAnnotation.class** on my own type casted sentences.

If anybody knows `how to create/set TreeAnnotation Parser using custom List<CoreMap> sentences`.

**OR**

How can I directly build **TreeAnnotation Parser** on **String sentences** **without** doing **type casting** them into **List** ? It will be more helpful for me. 
Any help ?

Answer (score 1):

If you have the parse tree of the sentence you can do it like that:

```
Annotation sentence = new Annotation ("your sentence");
sentence.set(CoreAnnotations.TokensAnnotation.class, sentenceTokens);// the token list
String t = "(S (NP ... ))";// your tree
TreeReader r = new PennTreeReader(new StringReader(t));
Tree tree = r.readTree();
sentence.set(TreeCoreAnnotations.TreeAnnotation.class, tree);
```

Comment: Hey, I don't the parse tree.

Comment: I don't want the parse tree. Need to create own in easy way. I meant that how you set `String t = ` variable. I need that parse tree.